# Which exception should be thrown/caught

Tags: java, exception

I apologize in advance if this question seems too silly or basic. But Google searches did not get me anywhere with this.

The code is simple:

```
public class Average3 {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {

      printAverage(100, 0);

    } catch (ArithmeticException ae) {

      ae.printStackTrace(); 

      System.out.println("Exception handled in " +
      "main().");

    }
    System.out.println("Exit main().");

  }

  public static void printAverage(int totalSum, int totalNumber) {
    try {

      int average = computeAverage(totalSum, totalNumber);// (8)
      System.out.println("Average = " +

          totalSum + " / " + totalNumber + " = " + average);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException iae) {

      iae.printStackTrace();

      System.out.println("Exception handled in " +
      "printAverage().");           
    }
    System.out.println("Exit printAverage().");

  }
  public static int computeAverage(int sum, int number) {
    System.out.println("Computing average.");

    return sum/number;

  }
}
```

Output:

```
Computing average.
java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
        at Average3.computeAverage(Average3.java:30)
        at Average3.printAverage(Average3.java:17)
at Average3.main(Average3.java:6)
Exception handled in main().
Exit main().
```

Here I was expecting IllegalArgumentException since the division by 0 happens in computeAverage which is called by printAverage. In my mind, the try statement should skip and it should move to the catch at this point registering an IllegalArgumentException.

I actually have a cloudy understanding but I want to know exactly what is going on and why. I've been racking my brains on this.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Why should it move to a `catch` of `IllegalArgumentException`?

Comment: because I thought that there is a try-catch block and failing a statement in try, it should move to catch

Comment: Why do you think you mention an exception type when using a `catch`? What does that type represent?

Comment: I would say it represents some kind of exception , i.e. subclass of Exception

Comment: That's not what I mean. What is it used for? Why do you specify some (or even any) specific type of exception? (It's all in the duplicate.)

Comment: As for your first question I believe that the exception type is mentioned in order to provide info about what went wrong

Comment: thanks for turning my attention to the other post. I'll go through it.

Comment: Could it be this simple? Division by zero produces an ArithmeticException. The ArithmeticException is not handled in printAverage so it bubbles up to main which handles it.

Comment: Yes, That's all there is to it.

Answer (score 0):

Exception should be thrown at `computeAverage` and caught at `printAverage`

Answer (score 0):

Your `computeAverage` invocation inside `printAverage` is throwing `ArithmeticException`, which you are not handling.

Therefore your `catch` statement for `IllegalArgumentException` is not executed, and execution stops at your statement:

```
System.out.println("Average = " + totalSum + " / " + totalNumber + " = " + average);
```

... throwing the `ArithmeticException`.

This is caught in your `main` method, and you then invoke `printStackTrace` on the `ArithmeticException`.

Therefore, you *may* want to `catch ArithmeticException` in your `printAverage` method instead of `IllegalArgumentException` (and possibly re-throw an `IllegalArgumentException`, wrapping in the `ArithmeticException` as root cause).

However, probably the best way to go would be to check for your arguments in the first place, and throw `IllegalArgumentException` if something will lead to division by `0`.

Comment: I got it now. Thanks.